Surface Charge Density At Boundary Between Vacuum And Linear Dielectric Within A Capacitor
In problem 4.19(b) from 'Introduction to Electrodynamics (Fifth edition)' By David J. Griffiths, we are given a capacitor (having its plates maintained at a constant potential difference V) with half its volume filled with a linear dielectric of some dielectric constant. Here, the goal is to find the electric field, polarization, electric displacement and surface and volume bound charges within the capacitor. (see figure)

My teacher had solved it by assuming a uniform electric field within all regions of the capacitor of magnitude V/d ('d' being the width of the capacitor), In the direction perpendicular to both the plates and going from the plate with higher potential to that with lower potential. After several unsuccessful attempts, I am unable to find a reason to explain why this is the only possible electric field within the capacitor for the given configuration. Why does the field have to be uniform within the capacitor? Why can't there be a field that is perpendicular to the plates (as they are conductors) but not uniform throughout? Is there some form of symmetry that I am missing?

Parallel plate capacitor problems are idealized. The idealization is a good enough approximation that it would be hard to measure the difference from the answer you get from using it.
The plates are assumed to be infinitely big with a uniform charge density. The field between infinitely big parallel plates is easily shown to be uniform and perpendicular to the plates.
Then the capacitor is assume to be a large section of those plates. The separation is much smaller than the side of the square. The field is nearly uniform except near the edge. The area near the edge is small compared to the interior. Edge effects are ignored.
In a real capacitor, the plates may be made of foil separated by a dielectric film. This is rolled up into a cylinder. The field is still close to uniform.
For this problem, you should continue to use the idealization. You can treat this as two capacitors side by side and ignore the small region where they touch.

In real capacitor of this type (with half space filled with dielectric) electric field won't be exactly uniform and perpendicular to plates everywhere (it wouldn't even if there was no dielectric). Lines of force of electric field near the edges of the capacitor will be as if repelled away.
Effect of this on capacitance can be neglected when the capacitor is thin enough, because then these edge effects take place in small part of the capacitor volume. That's why we can pretend the field is uniform. It isn't, but the difference is small and can be neglected.
The dielectric half slab won't affect this much, because when there is only a negligible gap between the plates and the slab, the contribution to line integral of electric field when going from one plate to another is negligible. Thus we can expect perpendicular component of electric field inside the dielectric to be the same as in the empty part of the capacitor.
Since both plates are equipotential plates, and net charge near one half-plate facing the dielectric (charge on the conductive plate plus charge on the dielectric slab face close to it) can have the same area density as the free charge on the exposed half-plate not facing the dielectric, and this fulfills all electrostatic conditions on charge density and potential, this is also what happens in equilibrium. The system has the same net charge distribution and thus the same electric field as a capacitor with the same voltage with no dielectric at all, or filled fully with any dielectric.
This would not be true if the slab was thinner than the capacitor. Then the polarization charge would be at different position from the free charge, and the field near the edges of the dielectric would be affected.
